# How to link IdentityUser to an Entity in EF Core with two DbContexts

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, dbcontext, clean-architecture

I'm trying to link `IdentityUser` to an Entity in EF Core but the problem is that I'm using a complex architecture ( clean architecture or at least very close to it ) and so I have multiple project and two of them have their own `DbContext` and trying to link my user to its saved items etc is becoming a pain.

Here's the problem:

- The solution name is `App`
- I have a couple of projects there: `App.Domain`, `App.Application`(ref to App.Domain), `App.Persistence`(ref to App.Application), `App.Identity`(ref to App.Application) and `App.API`(ref to App.Application, App.Persistence and App.Identity)
- `App.Persistence` has a DbContext -> `ApplicationDbContext : DbContext` containing all the `DbSets` in relation to the entities in `App.Domain`
- `App.Identity` has a DbContext as well -> `ApplicationIdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext` that's empty and exists only for `Identity` related tables
- I want my `ApplicationUser : IdentityUser` to be able to have properties in its model related to entities such as (namespace App.Identity.Models.ApplicationUser.cs)`public List<Item> SavedItems` and the other way around, I want to be able to have a property in the entity related to the user such as (namespace App.Domain.Entities.Item.cs)`public List<ApplicationUser>SavedBy`

I have asked someone that told me to create an abstraction of the `App.Persistence.ApplicationDbContext` that inherits from `App.Identity.ApplicationIdentityDbContext` where I would still define my DbSets as if it were the actual `ApplicationDbContext : DbContext` but where it really is `IApplicationDbContext : ApplicationIdentityDbContext` so that I would have only one DbContext and that would solve the problem.

I wanted to do this but I can't wrap my head around 2 things:

- Is this the right way to do it?
- How to do it?

I have also read that in a large project it's better to keep multiple DbContext to prevent multi-threading errors and stuff so I wanted to know what I should do here in order to have it work and potentially keep the benefit of having multiple DbContexts.

If you can give me a detailed explanation of your solution I would be so grateful because I would love to learn how you solved this problem I've been thinking about for weeks and maybe months now.

It seems that having only one DbContext is the solution, however `App.Persistence` requires a DbContext as well so I don't know what to do.

Do you think I should have the whole `App.Identity` project absorbed by the `App.Persistence` project since they have the same project references and have only one DbContext there inheriting `IdentityDbContext` ?

Comment: Just a small note: I think *"keep multiple DbContext to prevent multi-threading errors"* refers to context **instances**, not to context class definitions. In a multithreaded scenario you can happily create any number of context instances per task, but you should never share a single instance across concurrent tasks / threads.

Comment: Oh I see so having one DbContext is fine but make it a transient ?